# how to use where for relationship in laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to use where clause on the another relationship not my current selecting model as below table

```
table Customer
-------id-----customer_name

Table ModelA


table Customer
-------id-----fk_custome_id

table ModelB
-------id-----fk_ModelA_id
```

Function in Controller

```
$data['data'] = customer::with(['modelA','modelA.modelB'])
 ->where('fk_customer_id', 2)->get();
```

**Customer Model**

```
final function ModalA (){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ModelA', 'fk_customer_id', 'id');
}
```

**ModelA Model**

```
final function Modelb (){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ModelB', 'fk_modelA_id', 'id');
}
```

**Error:**
I will got error as below because select sql don't find the column name fk_customer_id in table customer, So how can I user fk_customer_id (in table ModelA) for where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can useYou can use `whereHas` like:

```
$data['data'] = customer::with(['modelA','modelA.modelB'])
     ->whereHas('modelA', function ($query) {
         $query->where('fk_customer_id', 2);
     })->get();
```

It's because when you're using with you just eager load constrints but you won't attach it to the main query (of the `customer` model). So there are two way: one modern with using `whereHas` or using `join` queries.